# C# 7.0 ValueTuples vs Anonymous Types

Tags: c#, tuples, anonymous-types, c#-7.0

Looking at the new C# 7.0 ValueTuples, I am wondering if they will completely replace `Anonymous Types`. I understand that `ValueTuples` are structs and therefore behave a bit differently than `Anonymous Types` which are classes. I don't see a use-case, however, in which I would prefer using an `Anonymous Type` over a `ValueTuple`.

Are there any use-cases where using an `Anonymous Type` would still be beneficial over using `ValueTuples` in C# 7.0?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Anonymous types are immutable, `ValueTuple`s are not. This is reflected in the fact that anonymous types expose properties, `ValueTuple`s expose fields. Data binding almost always requires properties.

Plenty of existing code only works with reference types, not with value types. What in particular comes to mind are projections in Entity Framework: projections to value types are simply not implemented.

Answer (score 10):

- anonymous types can carry name data *inwards*, but cannot express name data on *signatures*
- value tuples can express name data on *signatures*, but cannot carry name data *inwards*

Signature example:

```cs
(int Id, string Name) GetFoo(...) // could also use tuples in args, but not very useful
```

There is no way of doing this with anonymous types, as you cannot *express* the anonymous type other than as `object` on a signature.

"Inwards" example:

by this, I mean passing name data into *libraries*. For example, if we consider JSON:

```cs
var json = SomeJsonConvertAPI(new { Id = 42, Name = "abc" });
```

the library will be able to see the names `Id` and `Name`, and work accordingly (coming up with JSON like `{"Id":42,"Name":"abc"}`); however, this is *not* possible with value-tuples - any library, whether using `<T>` or `object` or something else, will only see the `Item1`, `Item2`, etc - with no mechanism to obtain the name data that exists at the originating site.

What would be *nice* would be something that is similarly terse to value-tuples and anonymous types, but which can be used in signatures *and* to pass inwards into libraries; and thus C# 9 gives you *records*:

```cs
record Foo(int Id, string Name);
```

which is short-hand for a `class Foo` with members `int Id {get;}` and `string Name {get;}` with all the constructor and equality bits you would expect.